# Python, why does my for loop creates two docx files when it should create one?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from docx import Document

root = Tk()



info = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]


vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = Label(root,text=i)
    btnYes = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = Radiobutton(root, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=4,row=idx, sticky = W)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)


def save():
    document = Document()

    #add table
    table = document.add_table(1, 4)
    #style table
    table.style = 'Table Grid'

    #populate header row
    heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
    heading_cells[1].text = "Yes"
    heading_cells[2].text = "No"
    heading_cells[3].text = "N/a"

    for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
        val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
        if val == 2:  # checks if yes
            cells[1].text = "*"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        elif val == 1:   # checks if no
            cells[2].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
            cells[3].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"

        fn = document.save("Test.docx")
        for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
            if cell.text == '*':
                fn = fn = document.save("failed.docx")
                break

        print(fn)

savebtn = Button(root, text = "Save", command = save).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If `no` has been selected for any of the options via the radio buttons, it then must save the document as `Failed.docx`. If every option has been selected without any `no's` then save the file as `Test.docx`.

**My problem is:**

Why is my last for loop and if statement is not working.

If I select multiple `no's` from the radiobuttons and click save, it generates me two files `Test.docx` & `Failed.docx`, whereas it should of created me just the one file `Failed.docx`

**My Goal**
My goal is to create radiobuttons, depending which option has been selected `Yes, no & N/A` it will generate a `docx` file.

For example, if none of the `no` has been selected, then generate a file called `Test.docx`.

If at least 1 or more `no` has been selected, then forget the `Test.docx` and create a different file name called `Failed.docx`

Comment: Your `text.docx` will be created every time you call `save()` function.

Comment: your line `fn = document.save("Test.docx")` is not submitted to any conditions, try putting it in a if

Comment: hi @Mayeulsgc edited my code in question.. still does the same

Comment: you didn't edit it, you line saving the document test.docs is still running everytime your run the function , without hecking the number of no selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if any of the options is 1 ('no') and change the filename according to the result.

```py
    no_in_result = any([var.get() == 1 for var in vars])
    doc_name = "Failed.docx" if no_in_result else "Test.docx"
    fn = fn = document.save(doc_name)
```

```py
from tkinter import *
from docx import Document

root = Tk()



info = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]


vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = Label(root,text=i)
    btnYes = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = Radiobutton(root, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=4,row=idx, sticky = W)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)


def save():
    document = Document()

    #add table
    table = document.add_table(1, 4)
    #style table
    table.style = 'Table Grid'

    #populate header row
    heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
    heading_cells[1].text = "Yes"
    heading_cells[2].text = "No"
    heading_cells[3].text = "N/a"

    for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
        val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
        if val == 2:  # checks if yes
            cells[1].text = "*"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        elif val == 1:   # checks if no
            cells[2].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
            cells[3].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"

    no_in_result = any([var.get() == 1 for var in vars])
    doc_name = "Failed.docx" if no_in_result else "Test.docx"
    fn = fn = document.save(doc_name)
    print(fn)

savebtn = Button(root, text = "Save", command = save).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

it's the **`fn = document.save("Test.docx")`** line that creates Test.docx every time. Here's a way to treat the problem :

```
from tkinter import *
from docx import Document

root = Tk()



info = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]


vars = []
for idx,i in enumerate(info):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    lblOption = Label(root,text=i)
    btnYes = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2)
    btnNo = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var, value=1)
    btnNa = Radiobutton(root, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0)
    lblOption.grid(column=4,row=idx, sticky = W)
    btnYes.grid(column=1,row=idx)
    btnNo.grid(column=2,row=idx)
    btnNa.grid(column=3,row=idx)


def save():
    document = Document()

    #add table
    table = document.add_table(1, 4)
    #style table
    table.style = 'Table Grid'

    #populate header row
    heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = "Options"
    heading_cells[1].text = "Yes"
    heading_cells[2].text = "No"
    heading_cells[3].text = "N/a"

    yes_flag = True

    for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = info[idx]  # gets the option name
        val = item.get()  #radiobutton value
        if val == 2:  # checks if yes
            cells[1].text = "*"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        elif val == 1:   # checks if no
            cells[2].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[3].text = "not-selected"
            yes_flag = False
        elif val == 0:   # checks if N/A
            cells[3].text = "*"
            cells[1].text = "not-selected"
            cells[2].text = "not-selected"
            yes_flag = False

        if yes_flag:
            fn = document.save("Test.docx")
        for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
            if cell.text == '*':
                fn = fn = document.save("failed.docx")
                break

        print(fn)

savebtn = Button(root, text = "Save", command = save).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of using a boolean flag, it's simpler to remember the filename to use directly.

Comment: you are right, i just wanted to point out the fact that the line was always been executed whenever `Save()` is called. What better than a bollean flag ! xD

Answer (score 2):

```
fn = document.save("Test.docx")
for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
        if cell.text == '*':
            fn = document.save("failed.docx")
            break
```

You are saving the document as Test.docx. Then you are looping through the table. When your if-condition is met, you save the document as failed.docx, but the original document is still saved as Test.docx - so you have two.

try something like:

```
filename = "Test.docx"
for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
        if cell.text == '*':
            filename = "failed.docx"
            break
document.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    fn = document.save("Test.docx")
    for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
        if cell.text == '*':
            fn = fn = document.save("failed.docx")
            break
```

There is no condition here for the first line; it is reached regardless of the data contents. Therefore `Test.docx` will be saved each time through the loop, and therefore it will be created as long as the loop runs at least once (which it will, because there are more than zero `vars`, each created from one of the `info` values).

Instead: use a variable to keep track of the filename to use, and then do the save once, *outside* the loop. In fact, the test logic should *also* be outside the main `for` loop, because you only need to search for `*` values once, after *all* the cell values have been put in place.

```
# determine all the data that goes in the spreadsheet
for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
    # do a bunch of stuff to set up `cells`
# Now decide whether there was a failure, and choose the docx name
filename = "Test.docx"
for cell in table.columns[2].cells[1:]:
    if cell.text == '*':
        filename = "failed.docx"
# and finally write the spreadsheet
fn = document.save(filename)
```

But better yet: you can fix the filename as part of the cell-populating logic, the moment that you write a `*` in the failure column:

```
filename = "Test.docx"
for idx, item in enumerate(vars):
    # other stuff....
    elif val == 1:
        # if we ever get in this block any time through the loop,
        # the test failed. After all, this is the case where we write the "*"
        # to column 2.
        cells[2].text = "*"
        cells[1].text = "not-selected"
        cells[3].text = "not-selected"
        filename = "failed.docx"
    # other stuff....
# At this point we don't need a separate checking loop; the filename is already set.
fn = document.save(filename)
```